# R - use Inf or Null

Tags: r

I often write functions in R where an argument should, in theory, be defaulted to Inf or -Inf.  However, it also makes sense to default the argument to NULL and check if a value for the argument has been provided.  For example consider these two functions

```
myfunc <- function(numVec, cap=NULL){
  if(!is.null(cap)) numVec <- pmin(numVec, cap)
  return(sum(numVec) + mean(numVec))
}

myfunc <- function(numVec, cap=Inf){
  numVec <- pmin(numVec, cap)
  return(sum(numVec) + mean(numVec))
}
```

They will always return the same result for the same input.  But which one is the better design?  The first method is probably slightly more efficient than the second, but the second is more elegant.  Obviously this is a very simple example, but does anyone have some good rules of thumb when faced with this design decision in general?

Comment: i'm not sure what the end goal might be with those parameters, but `is.finite` could be relevant

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this constitutes an answer, but it's too long for a comment and maybe it will help.

#### Size in memory

```
require(pryr)

object_size(Inf)
# 48 B
object_size(NULL)
# 0 B
```

#### Benchmarking

```
require(microbenchmark)

numVec2 <- numVec1 <- 1:3
cap1.1 <- Inf
cap2.1 <- NULL
cap2.2 <- cap1.2 <- 2
ex1.1 <- expression({ numVec1 <- pmin(numVec1, cap1.1); numVec1 })
ex1.2 <- expression({ numVec1 <- pmin(numVec1, cap1.2); numVec1 })
ex2.1 <- expression({ if(!is.null(cap2)) numVec2 <- pmin(numVec2, cap2.1); numVec2 })
ex2.2 <- expression({ if(!is.null(cap2)) numVec2 <- pmin(numVec2, cap2.2); numVec2 })

microbenchmark(ex1.1, ex1.2, ex2.1, ex2.2, times = 1000)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#   expr min   lq median    uq   max neval
#  ex1.1  42 46.5     50 116.5 33841  1000
#  ex1.2  40 46.0     49 117.5 23931  1000
#  ex2.1  42 48.0     52 116.0 28167  1000
#  ex2.2  47 53.0     55 122.0  3014  1000
```

#### Profiling

```
require(lineprof)

lp1.1 <- lineprof(eval(ex1.1), torture = TRUE)
lp1.2 <- lineprof(eval(ex1.2), torture = TRUE)
lp2.1 <- lineprof(eval(ex2.1), torture = TRUE)
lp2.2 <- lineprof(eval(ex2.2), torture = TRUE)

lp1.1
# Reducing depth to 2 (from 5)
#    time alloc release dups               ref       src
# 1 0.001 0.001   0.000    0      character(0)          
# 2 0.007 0.001   0.005    0            "eval" eval     
# 3 0.011 0.003   0.003    5 c("eval", "eval") eval/eval
lp1.2
# Reducing depth to 2 (from 5)
#    time alloc release dups               ref       src
# 1 0.001 0.001   0.000    0      character(0)          
# 2 0.012 0.004   0.001    5 c("eval", "eval") eval/eval
lp2.1
#    time alloc release dups          ref src
# 1 0.002     0       0    0 character(0)    
lp2.2
#    time alloc release dups               ref       src
# 1 0.001     0       0    0 c("eval", "eval") eval/eval
# 2 0.001     0       0    0      character(0)
```

So it seems (unsurprisingly) that checking `!is.null(caps)` is much more efficient overall than letting `pmin` handle `Inf`. So there's a tradeoff between ultra-efficient code and mathematical elegance.

However, it turns out that checking `cap != Inf` is *faster* than checking `!is.null(cap)`:

```
microbenchmark(!is.null(cap2.1), cap1.1 != Inf, times = 1000)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#              expr min  lq median  uq  max neval
#  !is.null(cap2.1) 130 145    152 203 4660  1000
#     cap1.1 != Inf  87 100    107 155 1317  1000
```

So it turns out that, in this case, you can have your cake and eat it, too:

```
myfunc <- function (numVec, cap = Inf) {
  if(cap != Inf) numVec <- pmin(numVec, cap)
  sum(numVec) + mean(numVec)
}
```